# Google Earth Engine: Cannot read property 'percentile' of undefined

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a problem running the code below. I'm using the API through Node js. I receive

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentile' of undefined

I don't understand why. Can you help me, please?

```
function test() {
      ee.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey(config.gee, async () => {

          console.log('init')
          var geometry = await ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-58.22065005792236, -38.39475941140011],[-58.21198115838623, -38.391698569574615],[-58.222109179626464, -38.38813303001853]]])

          var collection = await ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2').filterBounds(geometry).filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5));

          var cloudMasked = await collection.map((image) => {
            var cloud = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
            var cirrus = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();
            var qa = image.select('QA60');
            var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloud).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrus).eq(0));
            return image.updateMask(mask);
          });

          var ndvi = await cloudMasked.map((image) => {
            return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI'));
          });

          var reducer = ee.Reducer.percentile([90]);
          var ndvi90 = await ndvi.select(['NDVI']).reduce(reducer).clip(geometry);

          var url = await ndvi90.getDownloadURL({'scale': 10})

          console.log(url); 


      });
}
```

Is the use of async/await correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'percentile' of undefined

This means that you have not initialized the Earth Engine API with `ee.initialize()`. This is a separate step from authentication.

Many of the Earth Engine API calls are defined by the server, so they do not exist until the initialization, which downloads their declarations.

> Is the use of async/await correct?

No. Earth Engine's `ComputedObject`s are not `Promise`s, and awaiting them will do nothing. Promises are references to values that are *being computed;* a ComputedObject is a *description of how to compute* a value. EE API calls like `select()` compose into more complex ComputedValues, and the computation is actually started when you call an operation like `getDownloadURL`.

Just remove all of the `await` and your code will be correct (unless there's another problem you haven't seen and asked about yet).

Comment: Thank you Kevin! I actually have another question. In the above example I defined a triangle geometry to clip the image but I receive a square shape when I download the file. How can I clip it? I thought the `.clip()` call do it...

Comment: @Andrés Please ask that separately, preferably with a shorter but still demonstrative code example — questions in comments don't get seen by a wide audience and aren't as useful, and comments are only meant for discussing improvements to the question or answer they're associated with.